# Unable to run Node and Script in Desired State Configuration

Tags: powershell, azure, dsc, azure-resource-manager

### Background

I am provisioning a VM in Azure using an ARM template and created a Desired State Configuration .ps1 file that installs and configures IIS. So far so good.

I then added a `Script` block right next to the `Node` block.

Current set up:

```
Configuration Main
{
    Param ( [string] $nodeName )

    Import-DscResource -ModuleName PSDesiredStateConfiguration

    Node $nodeName
    {
        WindowsFeature WebServer
        {
            Name = "Web-Server"
            Ensure = "Present"
        }

        #other WindowsFeatures
    }

    Script FormatDiskScript
    {
        SetScript =
        {
            #Powershell to format disks
        }
        TestScript = { return $false }
        GetScript = { }
    }
}
```

Inside my ARM template, I have added the DSC extension to my VM and specified the `url` where to get the zip file, `script` to run  and `function` to invoke.

```
"properties": {
  "publisher": "Microsoft.Powershell",
  "type": "DSC",
  "typeHandlerVersion": "2.23",
  "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
  "settings": {
    "configuration": {
      "url": "[concat(parameters('_artifactsLocation'), '/', variables('dscArchiveFolder'), '/', variables('webvm_dscZipFileName'))]",
      "script": "webvm-dsc.ps1",
      "function": "Main"
    },
    "configurationArguments": {
      "nodeName": "[variables('webvm_name')]"
    }
  },
  "protectedSettings": {
    "configurationUrlSasToken": "[parameters('_artifactsLocationSasToken')]"
  }
}
```

### Question

It generates two .mof files and executes both the `Node` and `Script` sections however only the `Node` section completes successfully.

When I run with only the `Script`, that works, so the `Script` is valid. I just get the problem when running both of them.

This is what I see in the output in  C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Powershell.DSC\2.23.0.0\Status\0.status

```
Settings handler status to 'transitioning' 
Updating execution status 
DSC configuration completed
No meta mof back up file exist to restore ...
Settings handler status to 'error'
```

### Answer

After trying different approaches, I finally stumbled across one that worked. I simply placed the `Script` inside the `Node` instead of it being a peer:

```
Configuration Main
{
    Param ( [string] $nodeName )

    Import-DscResource -ModuleName PSDesiredStateConfiguration

    Node $nodeName
    {
        WindowsFeature WebServer
        {
            Name = "Web-Server"
            Ensure = "Present"
        }

        #other WindowsFeatures

        Script FormatDiskScript
        {
             SetScript =
             {
                 #Powershell to format disks
             }
             TestScript = { return $false }
             GetScript = { }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, no idea, haven't seen anything like this :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create 2 configurations inside DSC configuration (say Main and Manual) and put the thing you want executed with ARM Template into main and the other thing into manual

Or create 2 separate configurations in 2 separate files.

Comment: Actually, what I'm trying to do is have both the `Node` and `Script` sections executed with the ARM Template. I believe the ARM template only allows me to call one `function`, which in my case is the `Configuration Main`, so I need to somehow get that to run both `Node` and `Script`. Any ideas?

Comment: pretty sure it will run everything under main, so I don't see a problem @AndrésNava-.NET

Comment: You are correct, it does execute both the `Node` and `Script` sections. It generates two `.mof` files, however only the `Node` section completes successfully. When I run with only the `Script`, that works, so the `Script` is valid. I just get the problem when running both of them. Any ideas?